# mysql-python on Snow Leopard with MySQL 64-bit

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, 64-bit, 32-bit, mysql, python

Can't seem to get mysql-python to work on Snow Leopard for the life of me.

Currently using the default version of python that ships with Snow Leopard (`python 2.6.1`). Installed `MySQL 5.1.45 x86_64`.

I download the source for mysql-python http://sourceforge.net/projects/mysql-python/ and compile with the following commands:

```
tar xzf MySQL-python-1.2.3c1.tar.gz
cd MySQL-python-1.2.3c1
ARCHFLAGS='-arch x86_64' python setup.py build
ARCHFLAGS='-arch x86_64' python setup.py install
```

And am getting the following error when I try to import:

```
Python 2.6.1 (r261:67515, Jul  7 2009, 23:51:51) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5646)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import MySQLdb
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-universal/egg/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>

  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-universal/egg/_mysql.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-universal/egg/_mysql.py", line 6, in __bootstrap__
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/derek/.python-eggs/MySQL_python-1.2.3c1-py2.6-macosx-10.6-universal.egg-tmp/_mysql.so, 2): no suitable image found.  Did find:
/Users/derek/.python-eggs/MySQL_python-1.2.3c1-py2.6-macosx-10.6-universal.egg-tmp/_mysql.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture
```

Any ideas? Or the best route for starting over.

Answer (score 2):

I also encountered this problem, and did not find a solution.
Later changed to MySQL 32-bit, successfully installed the MySQL-Python, and problem solved~

Answer (score 1):

Delete already installed files, then try installing with the following command :

> sudo easy_install-2.6 mysql-python

Comment: Still getting an import error. `ImportError: dynamic module does not define init function (init_mysql)`

Comment: Did you remove previously installed files ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with [macport](http://www.macports.org/)?

```
sudo port install py26-mysql
```